# Calculate probability that at least one event occurs $n$ times

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am pretty stuck on how to solve problems like these :

$20$ train passengers will disembark randomly on the three following stations $S_1,S_2,S_3.$
What's the probability where at least one passenger disembarks on each one of the $3$ three stations ?

Comment: There is not enough information here.  A natural assumption (guess?) would be that each passenger independently chooses from the three uniformly at random.  Of course, that's not a sensible model for real train stops and, in any case, the distribution should be spelled out, not guessed at.

Comment: Yes , your assumption is right  , passengers choose their station randomly . I edited my question :)

Comment: You need to assume independence as well (no use if the $20$ are all going to the same wedding or whatever).

Comment: Hint:  how many possible outcomes are there?  How many of them have the property you desire?  For the second, you'll want to use Inclusion-Exclusion or something like it.

Comment: Easier to think about the probability that no passenger gets off on one of the stations.

Answer (score 0):

- For each of the $20$ passengers, $P_i(A)=P_i(B)=P_i(C)=1/3$

Assuming independance:

- Proba that everybody gets off in $A$ (resp, $B$, $C$): $(\frac{1}{3})^{20}$
- Proba that nobody gets off in $A$ (resp, $B$, $C$): $(\frac{2}{3})^{20}$

By inclusion-exclusion, the probability that at least one passenger disembarks on each one of the 3 three stations is:

$P=1-3*(\frac{2}{3})^{20}+3*(\frac{1}{3})^{20}$